# Perfect Forwarding Variadic Template to Standard Thread

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, stdthread, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to make a form of std::thread that puts a wrapper around the code executed in the thread. Unfortunately I can't get it to compile due likely to my poor understanding of rvalues and the `Function` templated type I'm trying to pass. Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

void Simple2(int a, int b) {}

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void Wrapper(Function&& f, Args&&... a) {
  f(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
}

class Pool {
 public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  void Binder(Function&& f, Args&&... a) {
    std::thread t(Wrapper<Function, Args...>,
                  std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...);
  }
};

int main() {
  Wrapper(Simple2, 3, 4);       // Works

  Pool pool;
  pool.Binder(Simple2, 3, 4);   // Doesn't compile
}
```

The Clang3.0 output that seems important here is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1286:9: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'void (int, int)' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'void (*)(int, int)'
```

and

```
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<void (void (&)(int, int), int &&, int &&), void (&)(int, int), int, int>' requested here
```

Which I think is hinting at a mismatch between `Wrapper<Function, Args...>` and the rvalues `f, a...` being given to std::thread.

Curiously this compiles in GCC4.9 and newer Clang if I change the `std::forward<Function>(f)` to `std::ref(f)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases where the difference between passing a function and passing a function pointer makes a difference.  If you do:

```
pool.Binder(&Simple2, 3, 4);
```

it should work.  Or alternatively you can have `Binder` decay its argument to a function pointer:

```
class Pool {
 public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  void Binder(Function&& f, Args&&... a) {
    std::thread t(Wrapper<typename std::decay<Function>::type, Args...>,
                  std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...);
  }
};
```

which in C++14 simplifies to:

```
class Pool {
 public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  void Binder(Function&& f, Args&&... a) {
    std::thread t(Wrapper<std::decay_t<Function>, Args...>,
                  std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...);
  }
};
```

Comment: This fixed things for g++4.7+. Unfortunately an error still persists in gcc4.6 of `invalid initialization of reference of type 'void (*&&)(int, int)' from expression of type 'void (*)(int, int)'`. Possibly this is a problem now with the stdlib that ships with gcc4.6.

Comment: You are a life saver. A whole day lost to this problem and I finally found the solution. Can you elaborate on why passing the function pointer makes the difference? Thousand thank yous.

Comment: @PauloNeves: Glad I could help.  When binding to a reference parameter, there is no "decay".  When binding to by-value parameters, some types decay: functions arguments decay to pointers to functions; array arguments decay to pointers to array-element-types;  top-level cv-qualifiers are discarded in a decay.  Function types are funny (in a bad way), you don't want to deal with them.  So it is usually best to decay function types to function pointer types. I forget all of the details for why function types are difficult to deal with.  I simply got shocked and learned not to touch the hot wire.