# Forward types in variadic template as values/references according to function signature

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, stdthread, perfect-forwarding

This question relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635924/perfect-forwarding-of-primitive-types), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235885/invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-with-c11-thread) and potentially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029048/perfect-forwarding-variadic-template-to-standard-thread).

I have the following class, in which the `AddFunction` method receives a function and a list of arguments to that function, then spawns an `std::thread` calling the passed function with the passed arguments:

```
class Processes {
public:
  Processes() {}

  ~Processes() {
    for (auto &t : threads_) {
      t.join();
    }
  }

  template <class Function, typename... Args>
  void AddFunction(Function &&func, Args &&... args) {
    threads_.emplace_back(std::forward<Function>(func),
                          std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
}
```

This results in a copy for every argument, and compilation will fail if an object is not copyable, because `std::thread` requires references to be wrapped in `std::ref` in order to guarantee that this object will exceed the thread's lifetime, and will copy it otherwise.

I want to pass objects by reference *when specified in the target function signature*.

I tried using a lambda:

```
template <class Function, typename... Args>
void AddFunction(Function &&func, Args &&... args) {
  threads_.emplace_back([&]() { func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); });
}
```

But this results in incorrect behavior, as the lambda captures values by reference before passing them by value, resulting in capture by reference behavior.

How do I implement a function that forwards arguments either as value or reference **according to the target function signature**?

---

*Example:*

```
void Foo(int a, std::vector<int> const &b) { /* ... */ }

int main() {
  Processes procs;
  int a = 6;
  std::vector<int> b;
  procs.AddFunction(
    Foo,
    a, // Should be passed by value
    b  // Should be passed by reference (as implemented by std::ref)
  );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might change function signature to be less generic:

First some helpers:

```
template <typename T> struct non_deducible { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;

template <typename T>
auto passed_by(T& t, std::true_type)
{
    return std::ref(t);
}

template <typename T>
T&& passed_by(T&& t, std::false_type)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

And then

```
template <class Ret, typename... Args>
void AddFunction(Ret (*func)(Args...), non_deducible_t<Args>... args) {
    threads_.emplace_back(func,
                          passed_by(std::forward<Args>(args),
                                    std::is_reference<Args>{})...);
}
```

Comment: This solved the question. I did not know you could unpack a function call in this way. What is the `{}` syntax? Is that just an empty constructor? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `type{}` is empty constructor of `type`, using `{}` syntax avoids vexing parse in some cases contrary to `type()` (even if here both would work).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go down the lambda route, you can implement some utilities that [allow you to capture by "perfect-forward"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html) - this means that *rvalues* are moved into the closure and *lvalues* are captured by reference. You can use `std::tuple<T>` to either store `T` or `T&` *(my linked article has a cleaner implementation)*:

```
template <class Function, typename... Args>
void AddFunction(Function &&func, Args &&... args) 
{
    threads_.emplace_back([
        targs = std::tuple<Args...>{std::forward<Args>(args)...},
        tfunc = std::tuple<Function>(func)]() mutable
    { 
        std::apply([&targs](auto&& x_func)
        {
            std::apply([&x_func](auto&&... x_args)
            { 
                std::forward<Function>(x_func)(
                    std::forward<Args>(x_args)...
                );
            }, targs);
        }, tfunc);
    });
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SDr8VLFwlnSAoYIK)